# Amazon rest service authentication and security

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, amazon-s3, hmac

I was reading about amazon's authentication process, and they use a custom process wich signs each request.

- I still don't understand how signing every requests stops from a man-in-the-middle atack, since everyone who sees the request and sees the signature, can issue the same request again.
- I would also apreciate if someone shared some bibliography about security or amazon web services or web services in general.
- How can SSL help in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/MakingRequests_RequestAuthenticationArticle.html) has to say.  Basically it boils down to the timestamp, and to mitigate against replay attacks, they suggest [using SSL](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1928).

> **Authenticating Requests**
>
> Requests to AWS are authenticated by verifying information contained
>   within the request. This verification is performed using the
>   information in the following table.

**AWSAccessKeyId**   The sender’s AWS account is identified by the Access Key ID. The Access Key ID is used to look up the Secret Access Key.

**Signature**   Each request to a web service that requires authenticated requests must contain a valid request signature, or the request is rejected. A request signature is
calculated using the Secret Access Key assigned to the developer's account by AWS, which is a shared secret known only to AWS and the developer.

**Timestamp**   The date and time the request was created, represented as a string in UTC. The format of the value of this parameter must match the format of the XML Schema dateTime data type.

The second link has this to offer:

> The best mechanism for defense against a replay attack is to ensure
>   all your requests are made over an SSL connection. If you cannot use
>   SSL, then the mechanism available to you for prevention of replay
>   attacks is the Expires parameter in signature version 2. This requires
>   your client to be synchronized to atomic time (using NTP, or a similar
>   synchronization protocol). If you do not use the Expires parameter,
>   and rely only on the timestamp parameter, your requests are subject to
>   a request expiration period, which varies by service, but can be as
>   long as 15 minutes.

Comment: So in order to completely be sure that I'm protected against man-in-the-middle attacks I have to use SSL?

Comment: SSL is a great defense against MITM attacks.

Comment: And how about if the signature is passed on the URL and not inside the request header?